# Phantom Out of Office

Tags: exchange, outlook-web-app, email

I have a user who has an out of office message that comes on every day before 8am. The user sets the out of office via Outlook web access from their device (Mac, iPhone, iPad, etc - whatever they have at the moment). The user has never used a windows device on our network.

I have run `Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -Identity user@example.com -AutoReplyState Disabled` on their account and still the message persists. I could set up a powershell script that does this every day, but when the user is gone on an extended time, I do not want to wipe their auto-reply.

Is there anything I can do to remove this phantom out of office reply?

**EDIT:**

Giving myself full access to the account and turning it off (even setting my own message) did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're talking OWA from their device the best course of action is to give yourself full mailbox access to their mailbox and then open it via OWA yourself.  Check for regular rules as well as Out of Office settings.  Then change it directly within their mailbox.

Comment: No rules existed, but the phantom message was there. I have changed it from OWA. I will know if that solved it by Monday.